# str error when replacing values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My code scrapes information from the website and puts it into a dataframe. But i'm not certain why the order of the code will give rise to the error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Basically, the data scraped has over 20 rows and 10 columns.

- Some values are within brackets `ie: (2,333)` and I want to change it to: `-2333`.
- Some values have words `n.a` and I want to change it to `numpy.nan`
- some values are `-` and I want to change them to `numpy.nan` too.

**Doesn't Work**

```
for final_df, engine_name in zip((df_foo, df_bar, df_far), (['engine_foo', 'engine_bar', 'engine_far'])):

# Replacing necessary items for final clean up

    final_df.replace('-', numpy.nan, inplace=True)
    final_df.replace('n.a.', numpy.nan, inplace=True)

    for i in final_df.columns:
        final_df[i] = final_df[i].str.replace(')', '')
        final_df[i] = final_df[i].str.replace(',', '')
        final_df[i] = final_df[i].str.replace('(', '-')

    # Appending Code to dataframe
    final_df = final_df.T
    final_df.insert(loc=0, column='Code', value=some_code)

# This produces the error - AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

**Works**

```
for final_df, engine_name in zip((df_foo, df_bar, df_far), (['engine_foo', 'engine_bar', 'engine_far'])):

# Replacing necessary items for final clean up

    for i in final_df.columns:
        final_df[i] = final_df[i].str.replace(')', '')
        final_df[i] = final_df[i].str.replace(',', '')
        final_df[i] = final_df[i].str.replace('(', '-')

    final_df.replace('-', numpy.nan, inplace=True)
    final_df.replace('n.a.', numpy.nan, inplace=True)

    # Appending Code to dataframe
    final_df = final_df.T
    final_df.insert(loc=0, column='Code', value=some_code)

# This doesn't give me any errors and returns me what I want.
```

Any thoughts on why this happens?

Comment: this is not reproducible with any dataframe, could you give a data example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works double [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) - first with `regex=True` for replace substrings and second for all values:

```
np.random.seed(23)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['(2,333)','n.a.','-',2.34], size=(3,3)), 
                  columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)
      A     B        C
0  2.34     -  (2,333)
1  n.a.     -  (2,333)
2  2.34  n.a.  (2,333)

df1 = df.replace(['\(','\)','\,'], ['-','',''], regex=True).replace(['-','n.a.'], np.nan)
print(df1)
      A   B      C
0  2.34 NaN  -2333
1   NaN NaN  -2333
2  2.34 NaN  -2333

df1 = df.replace(['-','n.a.'], np.nan).replace(['\(','\)','\,'], ['-','',''], regex=True)
print(df1)  
      A   B      C
0  2.34 NaN  -2333
1   NaN NaN  -2333
2  2.34 NaN  -2333
```

EDIT:

Your error means you want replace some non string column (e.g. all columns are `NaN`s in column `B`) by [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\(','-').str.replace('\)','')
                           .str.replace(',','')).replace(['-','n.a.'], np.nan)
print(df1)
      A   B      C
0  2.34 NaN  -2333
1   NaN NaN  -2333
2  2.34 NaN  -2333
```

---

```
df1 = df.replace(['-','n.a.'], np.nan)
       .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\(','-')
                         .str.replace('\)','')
                         .str.replace(',',''))
print(df1)
```

> AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index B')

[`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) of column `B` is `float64`:

```
df1 = df.replace(['-','n.a.'], np.nan)
print(df1)
      A   B        C
0  2.34 NaN  (2,333)
1   NaN NaN  (2,333)
2  2.34 NaN  (2,333)

print (df1.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C     object
dtype: object
```